# Is there any app, plugin or third party tool to breakdown a large javascript and generate libraries together with its directories

Tags: javascript

I have a huge javascript file that we want to breakdown and create libraries to represent all the API. Just imagine you want JQuery to be broken down then all its API be on their own separated js file and also be in their respective directories (I hope that makes sense).

Someone already shown me that there's something out there and I'm not sure if it's an app, plugin or third party tool, and I don't know what did he use or even how he done it. We are in need of that since that developer just simply vanished and can't be contact.

I'll appreciate your suggestions and hope to figure that out soon.

Comment: These kinds of questions are off-topic and there's no tool out there which will automatically organize your code. If there was, all of our lives would be easier.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please take a moment to review our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Mike C - Well that is what i thought, that is before I saw someone did it. I didn't ask him too much about it for i thought he would be around. Now that he's no where to find i'm starting to realise that i should have ask him how.